# XmlDocument missing Load method in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, xmldocument

I'm creating a Console App, .Net Core 1.1, and am trying to read an XML file. I brought in the System.Xml.XmlDocument nuGet package, created an XmlDocument, and then attempted to load using the file name. To my surprise, there is no overload for Load(string). See the attached image from the object browser. Is this permanently gone? I tried finding documentation, but was unsuccessful and mainly just found information like [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ReadingXmlDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            string content =
            doc.Load("Example.xml");
```

[image]

Comment: It seems they were removed: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4825

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `XmlDocument.Load(string)` method is part of `.NET Core 2.0` and `.NET Standard 2.0`. For `.NET Core 1.*`, you'll need to use the `Load(Stream)` method and pass it `FileStream` obtained via `File.Open`.

You can check the availability of the method at API .NET Catalog for [System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String)](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String))

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't able to get to the website, however, due to a "not issued by a trusted certificate authority" error.

Comment: Yeah StartCom was distrusted, there's an issue for that here: https://github.com/terrajobst/apisof.net/issues/3

Comment: Wow, that issue has been out there for 4 months.

Answer (score 0):

**see simple exemple:**

```
string sourceFileXML = @"c:\temp\file.xml";
var xml = new XmlDocument();
using (var sr = new StreamReader(sourceFileXML)) {
    xml.Load(sr);
}
```